# HTML is displaying only one object at index JS although there are more

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am creating a pdf, which I get the data from Frontend.
This data have different Array of Objects.
My problem it is if I have more than one object then the HTML will not show it, if I try to console log it, there are more objects.
Be aware this is generated in `mongoDB` for purpose to download pdf.
In the console log will show the array of object.
But in the HTML will render only one data, I think that problem it is in the `return` of the `HTML`.

Here is my code.

```
module.exports = (body) => {
let educationObj;

const json = body[1];
 json.education[0].subCategories.forEach(fields => {
 console.log(fields);
return educationObj = fields;
```

});
Here is the  return `<!doctype html>`and the whole  css and HTML.
}

This is how my Objects are.

```
{ name: 'Ukshtin Hoti Prizren',
  description:
   '<ul><li>wdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1&#10;&#10;dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwa</li></ul>',
  graduation: '2',
  startDate: '2020-09-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  endDate: '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  title: 'Computer Science',
  today: false }
{ description:
   '&#8226;&#9;Hn&#10;&#8226;&#9;J&#10;&#8226;&#9;K&#10;&#8226;&#9;K&#10;&#10;1.&#9;K&#10;&#10;2.&#9;K&#10;3.&#9;K34f',
  name: 'wewef',
  title: 'wwwww',
  graduation: 'errrt',
  startDate: '2020-10-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  endDate: '2020-10-31T00:00:00.000Z' }
```

And then in HTML I do call like this.

```
return `<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="education">
                    <div  class="Line-line-container" >
                      <div class="Line-line-line">
                        <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldField">
                          <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
                            <div  class="Text-Text-text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
                        <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
                          <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">
                            <b>${educationObj.title}</b>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
                        <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
                          <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">
                            ${educationObj.name}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
                        <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
                          <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">${educationObj.description}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the photo how it comes out.
[image]

Comment: you are not returning your map function results

Comment: @rags2riches what do you mean ?

Comment: You're overwriting the `educationObj` variable each iteration.

Comment: @Reyno and what is your idea, what I need to do ?

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi can you post the data from the `json` variable in your first snippet. I can then make a small example for you.

Comment: If you return the full HTML document for every iteration, then the output won't work. There can only be one <html> tag in one document

Comment: @Reyno I can add whole my json to see my data.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi Yes please, without it it will be really hard to create a solution

Comment: @Reyno Oke I will create a stackblitz and give the link.

Comment: @Reyno this is my `json`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-etkefb?file=test.json

Comment: @Carles what is then your idea about it ?
How can I achieve to show more than one <html> tag ?

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi I think you should remove opening and closing <html> and <body> tags from the template and try again. The library should place them automatically. I'm not sure, but I think the issue is that you are giving the whole HTML document structure for each template, and not simply the content of that HTML, so the library may understand that you are overwritting the full document, since <html> and <body> tags define the scope of the full document, not the part of it.

Comment: @Carles It didnt work :(

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi I'm sorry then!

Comment: @Carles No problem.

Answer (score 2):

In side your module.exports (getData) function you need to return from the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods. We also add a [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get a flatten version of the array back.

**Get data function**

```
module.exports = (json) => {
  return json.education.flatMap((education) => {
    return education.subCategories.map((element) => element);
  });
};
```

Before we can render the HTML we need to loop over all education objects and create the HTML for it. We first pass down the objects to a seperate function which creates the layout. At last we will return the HTML string to the function that will render it all.

**Returning of all html**

```
const createEducations = (educations) => {
  let result = "";

  for (const education of educations) {
    result += `
      <div  class="Line-line-container" >
        <div class="Line-line-line">
          <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldField">
            <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
              <div  class="Text-Text-text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
          <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">
              <b>${education.title}</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
          <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">
              ${education.name}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Field-field-fieldBase first-template-fieldValue">
          <div class="Text-Text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text-wrapper">${education.description}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  return result;
};

const getHTML = (educations) => {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="education">
          ${createEducations(educations)}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>`;
};

const educations = getData(/* the body with json you pass down */);
return getHTML(educations);
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't have only `Educations` as you maybe saw in the json file.
I have there more for example, Career and other things.
Do I need to follow the same way for every SubCategory ?

Comment: It depends of what you need, if they all have the same output you can do it in one go. Otherwise a similar setup can be done for each category. Though repeating would go against the whole [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) concept

Comment: I need all of them to show at pdf.
I have heard about a library called Handlebars, which is good for this exampljes do you know something about it ?

Comment: Ye i worked with [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) it works pretty good. Not sure about creating a pdf though. FYI: Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ezttfn?file=index.js) using all different categories. Good luck on creating a pdf from it

Comment: I am getting `document.body.innerHTML = getHTML(json);`  (node:15736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: I want only to create template with handlebars, and then this template to download als pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are not returning the elements in the nested map function, but still, you are able to log your objects inside it. Also, the second map function is unnecessary since you already have the object fields you want to return in the outer map.

Change your logic to this, using just one foeEach loop function:

```
json[0].education[0].subCategories.forEach(field => {
    // console.log("fields", field);  // test logs for all fields
    // update your dom elements with fields content
    your_dom_elements.forEach(elem => { // update you Dom elems with fields
       elem = fields;
    }) 
});
```

if you **need** to use map, and do not need to iterate just to reassign a variable over and over, use just one map function. This solution is hard coded into your data, so ideally you should design your data based on the operations you want to run...

If you really want to reassign a variable for each field and really think map is needed:

```
return json[0].education[0].subCategories.map(field => {
  your_dom_elems.map(elem => {
     return elem = field;
  });
});
```

If this answer helps you solving your issue, **consider** accepting the answer or upvoting it. Thanks.

Comment: nope it is the same problem.
I declare before initialization `let educationObj`

Comment: what does json look like?

Comment: I repeat, you are not returning from the inner map function and if you still have the same issue, I would like to see how you populate the objects in the DOM. You do not need to declare the variable outside because map can return that element on each iteration. In fact, the inner map may not be needed at all since you are just reassigning the iterated objected to a variable declared outside.

Comment: this is my json https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-etkefb?file=test.json

Comment: how can I have acces to `element` if I dont declare, my HTML will not know what is the `element` in the map return.

Comment: it's the element passed as first argument to the map method...no need to declare it outside and no need to use map because you are not mapping anything. You just using map to reassign the element passed as arg to a variable, without returning it. In this case best (and more semantically correct, to use just a for or forEach loop. Working on a new solution now

Comment: thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: @rafs2riches I tried your code but it is the same problem.
It shows only once.

Comment: shows only once what? can you edit your post please so I can see what the issue is?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: If you use forEach, you need to reassign your variable inside the loop, not after the for loop has finished. That's why you only get one result. Take a look at my edited solution.

Comment: I have writed like this.
`json.education[0].subCategories.map(fields =>  educationObj = fields);` It is not working it is the same output.

Comment: this is not possible, you need to show me your output and what is expected. Look at these test with the forEach loop as above: `fields {
  name: 'Ukshtin Hoti Prizren',
  description: '<ul><li>wdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1&#10;&#10;dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwdw1dwa</li></ul>',
  graduation: '2',
  startDate: '2020-09-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  endDate: '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  title: 'Computer Science',
  today: false
}`

Comment: and...`fields {
  description: '&#8226;&#9;Hn&#10;&#8226;&#9;J&#10;&#8226;&#9;K&#10;&#8226;&#9;K&#10;&#10;1.&#9;K&#10;&#10;2.&#9;K&#10;3.&#9;K34f',
  name: 'wewef',
  title: 'wwwww',
  graduation: 'errrt',
  startDate: '2020-10-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  endDate: '2020-10-31T00:00:00.000Z'`

Comment: if you are using map, the global varibale gets reassigned each time the map function processes your element...so you either are not implementing the function correctly or you are not updating the DOM **for each element** you are processing

Comment: i will all my file now to see.

Comment: what? Can you see all the fields in your front end now? see my edited solution. You are making me sweat for a simple solution :)

Comment: `return json[0].education[0].subCategories.map(field => {
  your_dom_elems.map(elem => {
     return elem = field;
  });
});`
what is the `your_dom_elems` I dont understand ?

Comment: it's a placeholder, a fictituous var for the dom elements you want to use to show the contect of the fields you are interested in. You need to iterate through your DOM elems to show all the fields. I have done my very best to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225322/discussion-between-rags2riches-and-abedin-zhuniqi).

Comment: Did you edited your answer ?